# Mysql syntax error in delete trigger

Tags: mysql, triggers

Could anyone tell me that what is the syntax error in this trigger

```
DELIMITER |

CREATE TRIGGER User_XEntity_Before_Delete

BEFORE DELETE

   ON UserXEntity FOR EACH ROW

BEGIN

   -- Insert record into Delete_UserXEntity table
   INSERT INTO Delete_UserXEntity
   ( DeletedUserXEntityId,
     UserId,
     CreatedAt)
   VALUES
   ( OLD.Id,
     OLD.UserId,
     NOW() );

END;

|

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Trigger looks good, are you adding it on mysql terminal or some other client like phpmyadmin ?

Answer (score 1):

I've got the solution. Actually I was entering this code in `phpmyadmin` Trigger window, where it asks about table name, time and event already. So we only need to write the trigger action code in that window. I was writing the whole trigger code and that's why I was giving me a syntax error.

We only need to write the following code in `PHPMYADMIN` add new trigger windows:

```
INSERT INTO Delete_UserXEntity
   ( DeletedUserXEntityId,
     UserId,
     CreatedAt)
   VALUES
   ( OLD.Id,
     OLD.UserId,
     NOW() );
```